# What are the origins of standard port numbers?

Tags: port-number

Wikipedia has a [long list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) of standard port numbers for various protocols.

Does anyone know how some of these numbers were chosen?

**EDIT**: I'm asking how/why the original developers chose the numbers, not where the list comes from.

Comment: I put this on SO instead of SU or SF because I'm asking how the developers chose the numbers in the first place.

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: because it's not programming related, subjective and requires extended discussion.

Comment: @SLaks: Community Wiki because some of the folks that picked these numbers are dead -- the "origin" is very likely lost with them.  Also, the answer does not solve any problem that anyone has.  You have no program which is broken.  You have no coding problem that can be solved by this trivia.

Comment: For folks who invented these numbers who've died see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Postel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [mailing list thread](http://mailman.postel.org/pipermail/internet-history/2006-January/000519.html) has some insight

Answer (score 1):

The first reference to a registry of well known numbers seems to be [RFC 322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc322), from 1972. [RFC 433](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc433) is the first official compilation of such a registry. There is a bit of background on Wikipedia describing the [history of the IANA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority#History_of_IANA) which talks about this.

Comment: I'm asking how/why the original developers chose the numbers, not where the list came from.

Comment: The second RFC I linked to says the initial list was decreed by Jon Postel, who had ultimately authority. Presumably some were already in common usage, but the decision on official numbers for many ports was made at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Read the wikipedia page on the [IANA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority) (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority).  Early on the designers of the protocols picked the port numbers and maintained a registry.  Overtime these became the official numbers and people agreed to use them for those protocols and not for other programs.  Eventually these became codified in the RFCs and the IANA was born to manage the process.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the port numbers are handed out by http://iana.org.